# Dropdown menu dynamically populates a second dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I had some code where the first dropdown menu dynamically populates a second dropdown menu using PHP and JQuery.

The code used

```
$('#first_choice').change(...)
```

and inside this function a `getter.php` file loaded the data from a database for the second menu using the first choice value, like so:

```
 $first_choice=$("#second-choice").load(
            "getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val()
  );
```

This php page was json encoded.  Inside the change function there was a `.get()` function having the url of the select menu php page, a function(data) to append to the second menu's's options and the format "json" as the last parameter.  The change function was called once to change the second menu when the first menu is clicked.  I remember the `.ajax` parameter was false.

Comment: Try splitting your question into paragraphs with proper formatting.

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

example for ajax second dropdown menu change when first dropdown menu change:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#first_choice').change(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "getter.php?choice=" + $(this).val()
                }).done(function(data){
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    var html = '';
                    for(i=0;i<data.length;++i){
                        html += '<option value="'+data[i]+'">'+data[i]+'</option>';
                    }
                    $('#second-choice').html(html);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        {padding:0;margin:0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="first_choice">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <select id="second-choice">
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

code in the processing file "getter.php" :

```
<?php
$out = array();
if(isset($_GET['choice']))
{
    for($i=100;$i<10000000;$i*=10)
    {
        $out[] = $_GET['choice']*$i;
    }
}
echo json_encode($out);
?>
```